# Skip link default behavior rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little problem: I have a file stored in `public/uploads//paper/foo/bar`. This file is stored here by [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) (gem for file upload). Now, I want to put a link in my project to this file, but if I do like this:  `<a href="<%=a.document%>"> <%=a.name%></a>` I get a routing error like this: `No route matches [GET] "/uploads/paper/foo/bar/file.pdf"`.

How can I skip this default behavior of links in rails?

Comment: Are you sure that file is present at uploads/paper/foo/bar/file.pdf ?
Try 
ls uploads/paper/foo/bar/file.pdf
in terminal

Comment: File is there. I tested this.

Answer (score 1):

This probably due to `config.serve_static_files` is not set to true in `config/enviroments/development.rb` or whichever environment you are running (defaults to true for development and false for production)